# Query on partial date search

Tags: sql

So I am trying to figure out the correct syntax on the following. Basically I have a Datetime Column that I need do search ONLY on the "DD-MM". I am having a hard time with the syntax and can't seem to ask the right question on the good ol' interwebs. Here is my example.

I need this:

```
SELECT someDate FROM someTable

WHERE someDate = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

To Look like this:

```
  SELECT someDate FROM someTable

  WHERE someDate = 'MM-DD'
```

Comment: Which dbms you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many databases support `to_char()` (or a similar function):

```
where to_char(someDate, 'MM-DD') = 'MM-DD'
```

More support functions to extract month and date:

```
where month(someDate) = MM and day(someDate) = DD
```

The standard functions are a bit more verbose:

```
where extract(month from someDate) = MM and extract(day from someDate) = DD
```